# Copy dlls that are not referenced in the project into published folder in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, deployment, assemblies, publish

I m generating resource assemblies from text files by executing a bat file in the pre-build event and copying them into bin folder. These resource assemblies are therefore not referenced in the project.

At present I need to manually copy these dlls into published folder.
Is there a clean way that ensures that everytime I publish, the required dlls are copied into published folder.

Note: I do not want to hard code physical path for deployment folder in the bat file/ or prebuild events.

Comment: Please refer :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Manoj Mevada. I m able to publish using web deploy. But my question is regarding "inclusion of dlls not referenced in the project... and are made available in bin after pre-build event"

Answer (score 0):

Please select the DLL and open Property and Marked "Copy Local" as True. Please refer below image. it may help you.

[image]